# Get details of linked collection inside another collection using populate()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous, mongoose

I am trying to build a system to record timesheets. For each day, an employee can record different hours, against different tasks assigned to them. Every entry in my Timesheet collection contains an array of individual timesheet entries. Sample data/schema for this collection:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5db2c672620ed61854818ccd",
        "EmployeeId": "5da9aed442e3070bbd9f7581",
        "TimeSheet": [
            {
                "_id": "5db2c672620ed61854818ccf",
                "TaskId": "5db14152e6537a05258bf573",
                "Hours": "2.5",
                "Remarks": "Test 2.5"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5db2c672620ed61854818cce",
                "TaskId": "5db1886ee6537a05258bf575",
                "Hours": "11.5",
                "Remarks": "Test 11.5"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

For the corresponding Task collection, the data resides in the following way -

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5db14152e6537a05258bf573",
        "EmployeeId": "5da9aed442e3070bbd9f7581",
        "ProjectId": "5db141d9e6537a05258bf574",
        "TaskName": "Finish the timesheet page",
        "TaskDescription": "Write the front-end and back-end code to allow employees to record their timesheets."
    },
    {
        "_id": "5db1886ee6537a05258bf575",
        "EmployeeId": "5da9aed442e3070bbd9f7581",
        "ProjectId": "5db141d9e6537a05258bf574",
        "TaskName": "Learn Populate",
        "TaskDescription": "Learn how MongoDB/Mongoose uses the equivalent of SQL joins"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5db27e3ca2445c05255dbad0",
        "EmployeeId": "5da9aed442e3070bbd9f7581",
        "ProjectId": "5db141d9e6537a05258bf574",
        "TaskName": "Timesheet save API",
        "TaskDescription": "Code the API to save a timesheet to the database"
    }
]
```

I am trying to get the Task details (TaskName, TaskDescription and others) into every individual task-timesheet entry. For this, I tried using the `populate()` method in my controller, like so -

```
exports.findByEmployee = (req, res) => {
    TimeSheet.find({ EmployeeId: req.query.EmployeeId })
        .then(timesheets => {
            timesheets.forEach((ts, ts_index) => {
                ts.TimeSheet.forEach((item, index) => {
                    Task.findById(item.TaskId).populate('TaskId').exec((err, taskDetails) => {
                        item.TaskDetails = taskDetails;
                    })
                });
            })

            res.send(timesheets);

        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving timesheets."
            });
        });
}
```

However, the API response (for getting all timesheets) does not contain a key called `TaskDetails` in the individual task-timesheet section. My guess is that because of asynchronous nature of the function calls, the part `res.send(timesheets)` is getting fired before the section above it has had the time to finish. So my question is, how do I fix this? To summarize, I want the Task details from the Task collection with every individual timesheet item that is linked to the Task by id. Also, is this the correct way to use `populate()`, or is there a better/simpler/more correct way that will solve my problem?

EDIT:
Someone requested the models, so here's task and timesheet:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

const TaskSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    EmployeeId: ObjectId,
    ProjectId: ObjectId,
    TaskName: String,
    TaskDescription: String
}, { collection: 'TASK' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', TaskSchema);
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

const TimeSheetSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    EmployeeId: ObjectId,
    Date: Date,
    TimeSheet: [
        {
            TaskId: {
                type: ObjectId,
                ref: 'TASK'
            },
            Hours: String,
            Remarks: String
        }
    ]
}, { collection: 'EMPLOYEE_TIMESHEET' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('TimeSheet', TimeSheetSchema);
```

Comment: Can you add TimeSheet,  Task and TaskDetails models to the question?

Comment: @SuleymanSah added. I don't have separate models for Task and TaskDetails, I'm saving all things task-related to the same collection.

Comment: You are accessing db in a loop over in a loop, the performance will badly suffer when hundreds of collections appear.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on here. 1) `TaskId` doesn't exist in the Task collection so populate doesn't work (and there is no need to use it there) 2) the `item` object you declare in your `ts.TimeSheet.forEach()` will not exist outside of that forEach() loop so adding `taskDetails` to it doesn't accomplish anything because the `item` object is destroyed when the forEach() loop finishes.

I believe what you want is something like:

```
exports.findByEmployee = (req, res) => {
  try {
    // returns just the TimeSheet object from within the TimeSheet collection 
    // (recommend renaming one of these to avoid confusion!)
    TimeSheet.find({ EmployeeId: req.query.EmployeeId }, 'TimeSheet')
      // populates TaskId (which I recommend renaming 'Task') 
      // with the details from the Task collection
      .populate('TimeSheet.TaskId')
      // executes the query
      .exec(timesheets => {
        // sends the object once the query has finished executing
        res.send(timesheets);
      });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: err.message || 'Some error occurred while retrieving timesheets.',
    });
  }
};
```

I would highly recommend the MDN ["Local Library" Express tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose) for a good introduction to working with MongoDB and Mongoose.

Comment: This is great, and looking at it, I sort of understand why/how it should work. However, when I try it, it gives me the error message "Schema hasn't been registered for model \"TASK\".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)" Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: It's telling you it can't find the model called 'TASK'. You've named your model 'Task' (lowercase) in `module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', TaskSchema);`, but you are using `ref: 'TASK'` (uppercase) in your TimeSheetSchema. Change it to `ref: 'Task'` and it should find it

Comment: Now everything is blank, it's not returning any data. Could you please explain what you did in the `find()` step? I looked at the official Mongoose API docs, couldn't find a second parameter of the type string.

Comment: I've renamed the object to avoid confusion with the TimeSheet collection:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

const TimeSheetSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    EmployeeId: ObjectId,
    TimeSheetDate: Date,
    TimeSheetPerTask: [
        {
            TaskId: {
                type: ObjectId,
                ref: 'Task'
            },
            Hours: String,
            Remarks: String
        }
    ]
}, { collection: 'EMPLOYEE_TIMESHEET' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('TimeSheet', TimeSheetSchema);
```

Comment: An example from the [Mongoose find() docs] (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find): `// executes, name LIKE john and only selecting the "name" and "friends" fields
MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }, 'name friends', function (err, docs) { })` so the string contains fields you want to return. It's optional. If you don't supply it, all data from the find() will be returned. Following your renaming, you will want to return 'TimeSheetPerTask'